# Can do browser back or forward action in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can do browser back or forward action in chrome extension? Is there any related api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject [**`Content Scripts`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) and execute [**`window.history`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) methods for browser back and forward actions.